# How is this code assuming little endian is being used?

Tags: endianness

In an article explaining little versus big endian it said the folowing code was making the assumption that it was running on a little endian machine.

The reason it says for the assumption is "The switching of the bytes is being assumed in the 'C' structure." I don't understand where the assumption is.

struct
   {
      WORD y;
      WORD x;
   } POS;

lparam = (DWORD) POS;

Comment: Do you expect `x` to hold the MSB or the LSB of the DWORD?  Also, you might want to think about accepting some answers on your other questions.

Comment: What I've posted is what the article says in its entireity regarding this struct, its says noting about msb or lsb.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this, `x` is (0x1234) and `y` is (0x5678) and the intention is to have `lparam` be (0x12345678).

The code from the example will cause `lparam` to be (0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12) on a little endian machine, which is (0x12345678) as intended.

However on a big endian machine `lparam` will be (0x56 0x78 0x12 0x34) which is (0x56781234).  Therefore this code was written with the assumption that it was for little endian.